# dictionary and loops in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Make a dictionary called cities Use the names of three cities as
keys in your dictionary Create a dictionary of information about each city and
include the country that the city is in, its approximate population, and one fact
about that city The keys for each city’s dictionary should be something like
country, population, and fact Print the name of each city and all of the information you have stored about it.

My code:

```
cities={

"Egy":{
    "name":"egypt",
    "capital":"cairo",
"population": "100,000",
    "fact":"civilization"
},


"leb":{
    "name":"lebanon",
    "capital":"beiruit",
"population": "10,000",
    "fact":"beautiful"
},


"moroc" :{
    "name":"morocco",
    "capital":"rabat",
"population": "1000,000",
    "fact":"food"
}
}

for city, city_info in cities.items():
    print ("I love "+ city+ " and here's what I know about  it: ")

for info in city_info:
    print("the full name of the country is " + city_info["name"] + " its capital is " + city_info["capital"]+
          " the number of population is "+ city_info["population"] + " the most famous fact about it is " + city_info["fact"])
```

I would like to print the two loops together so that each country will be in one sentence( I have not studied functions yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the second loop; you can simply do so:

```
for city, city_info in cities.items():
    print ("I love "+ city+ " and here's what I know about  it: the full name of the country is " + city_info["name"] + " its capital is " + city_info["capital"]+
          " the number of population is "+ city_info["population"] + " the most famous fact about it is " + city_info["fact"])
```

Which will produce the following output:

```
I love Egy and here's what I know about  it: the full name of the country is egypt its capital is cairo the number of population is 100,000 the most famous fact about it is civilization
I love leb and here's what I know about  it: the full name of the country is lebanon its capital is beiruit the number of population is 10,000 the most famous fact about it is beautiful
I love moroc and here's what I know about  it: the full name of the country is morocco its capital is rabat the number of population is 1000,000 the most famous fact about it is food
```